# Generating 2 values from one method

Tags: java

I need to be able have the value of number and numberCount from the method for Input Method.

The assignment I am doing is this...

Design and implement a Java program that will gather a floating point numbers and determine the sum and average of the data entered. The program should use separate methods for inputting the data, calculating the sum, calculating the average, and displaying the results. A sentinel value should be used to indicate the user has completed entering their numbers.  The output should display a message that includes the count of the numbers entered, the sum of the numbers and the average of the numbers. If the sum of the numbers is greater than 100, a warning message should be displayed indicating “values have exceeded a sum 100”.

1. Additional requirements include:

a.       Use JOptionPane.showInputDialog() methods for your user to input their data

b.      Use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() methods to display your messages.

This is what I have so far...

```
// Import javax JOptionPane
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// Create Class
public class Test {

  // Main Method
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Initialize values
  int numberCounter = 0;
  int count;

  double sum = 0;
  double number = 0;
  double average;

  double numberString=0;
  number = readDouble(numberString, number, sum, numberCounter);
  numberCounter = read1Double(numberString, number, sum, numberCounter);

  // Initiate loop if user entered at least one value display average, count, sum
  if ( numberCounter != 0 ) {

   // Promote numberCounter to double and calculate average of all numbers entered
   average = avg(sum, numberCounter);

   // Calculate count
   count = numberCounter;

   // Display average, count and sum.
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum of numbers input : " + sum + "\nCount of   
    numbers : " + count + "\nAverage of numbers : " + average);
   }
    // Initiate loop if sum exceeds 100 display message
    if ( sum >= 100 ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of inputed numbers exceeds 100!");
    }
  }

  // Average Method
  private static double avg(double s, double c) {
  return (s/c);
  }

  // Sum Method
  private static double sum(double s, double c) {
  return (s+c);
  }

  // Input Method
  private static double readDouble(double i, double number, double sum, int numberCounter) {

    // Acquire first number from user
    String numberString;
    numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    "Enter integer number :" );
    number = Double.parseDouble( numberString );

      // Initiate loop until stopped by user by using sentinel value of -1
      while ( number != -1 ) {
      sum = sum(sum, number);
      numberCounter = numberCounter + 1;

      // Acquire the remaining numbers from user until stopped
      numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
      "Enter integer number or -1 if no more numbers to insert :" );
      number = Double.parseDouble( numberString );
      }
    return number;   
  }
  }
}
```

Thanks a ton for the responses, but could I get like an example of how it would be used in my script? Im so confused, with little sleep and everything the last day has been this assignment Im pretty fried. Haha Java sure can wear you down.

And yeah it doesn't work but I need the values from the Input Method in my main method so the output data is correct.

My class has yet to do arrays yet, so my instructor is expecting something less than an Array.

Comment: what's the problem? Hoping you'll say something else than "it doesn't work".

Comment: @user951376: We will not do your homework. You should decouple things. First collect user input, then perform calculations, and then display the result including warnings.

Comment: I do apologize if it seems as if I am asking someone else to do my homework. I have no issue doing it myself, I am just stuck and need help understanding this.

Comment: @user951376: See my answer, maybe that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Although, @Puller's answer is the most traditional way of doing this. This this comes up over and over again I suggest looking at FunctionalJava's P set of classes. There is P1-P8 which wrap 1-8 objects respectively. There is a simple set of methods **P.p** which create the appropriate version of P1-P8 for you.

[P Class API](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/P.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your ad-hoc class which contains the values you have to return, and make that method return a reference to the ad-hoc object.

```
[inside your class]

public class MyReturnValues {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

[...]

MyReturnValues myMethod() { ... }
```

Comment: Im going to try this class, Im just having trouble understanding what I put for a and b would it be the 2 values I need? And how does this class associate itself with the method created to get the values and spit it back to the main class as the values intended?

Comment: Yes, a and b (and any other variable you might need) are the values you have to get as the method return. From the user perspective it will be something like `MyReturnValues mrs = myObject.myMethod(); x = mrs.a; z = mrs.b;` However I suggest you to look at @"John B" answer in order to definitively solve the "multiple return values" issue in Java.

Comment: I have looked at John B's post but I am trying to read the info in the link he provided and I can wrap my head around it, what the P p does and how it works, Everything I have been doing in JAVA up until now has made sense and I can link things together but this is beyond me, as for what you posted I dont understand what mrs is like mrs.a and mrs.b, thanks for your input. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I pasted a full example at pastebin. Hope this helps :). [pastedCode](http://pastebin.com/a71cZFtc)

Answer (score 0):

The input method does not need to calculate the sum and average (and it's not its job), but simply get and return the inputs. Have the method return what was input (e.g. an array), and then pass that array to your sum and average methods.

Comment: My class has yet to go over arrays, I need to find a different solution. Any more ideas? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the different tasks you try to accomplish:

1. Retrieve user input: `double[] inputs = readInput();`
2. Perform calculations: `double sum = sum(inputs); double avg = avg(inputs);`
3. Display messages

This is not a perfect OO solution but it should cover all the requirements you listed in your question.

Comment: It's 'your' method, you have to implement it :-)

Comment: Oh okay, are there any values I have to put in the brackets for double[]? so it would look like double[] input = readDouble(numberString, number, sum, numberCounter) { ?

Comment: No, inside `readInput` iterate as long as the user did not finish. Then return an array containing all user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public class TwoTuple<A, B> {
   public final A firstl;
   public final B second;
   public Two Tuple(A a, B b) { first = a; second = b; }
   public String toString() {
      return "(" + first  ", " + second ")";
   }
}
```

Then use above class for your return value:

```
public class Test {

  static TwoTuple<Double, Double> yourMethodName(YourInputs){
     .......
     return new TwoTuple<Double, Double>(YourSumResult, YourAverageResult);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoTuple<Double, Double> result = yourMethodName(YourInputs);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting class, interface or enum expected when trying this on the public static TwoTuple<Double, Double> readDouble(numberString, number, sum, numberCounter) { line. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you define "public class TwoTuple<A, B>" in separated file and use it in test class?

Comment: Oh no, I have not, so I make a new .java named TwoTuple, define that. save it and compile it for it to work?

Comment: Yes, and make it in the same package with test.java

Comment: I cant get the TwoTuple class to compile, it errors on public Two Tuple(A a, B b) { first = a, second = b; } string saying there should be a ; after first = a. Then it errors on the return string expecting a few ; too. Any ideas?

Comment: @user951376 I fix the error, you must replace "," after first = a to ";".